# How to Interface MATLAB with XCode

Tags: xcode, matlab, matlab-engine

I'm currently developing part of an iOS project that requires classification algorithms from MATLAB. I have tried building an engine application on XCode but during runtime it crashes due to this error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _engOpen
Referenced from: /Users/Edmund/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test- 
efqngrqojbuyvtbqcjngyfblxxpt/Build/Products/Debug/Test
Expected in: flat namespace
```

I followed the instructions thus far from http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4CKF73/?solution=1-4CKF73.

Anyone with experience on MATLAB-XCode interfacing help?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH env. variable to point to matlab engine runtime libraries. Check [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/compiling-and-linking-mat-file-programs.html#f28833) how to do that.

Before executing try "otool -L" on the executable to see if all linked libraries can be found.